# Why is it every time we deploy our custom function users experience #ERROR! for some time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, custom-function

Each time we deploy our Google AppScript Project, our custom function starts returning `#ERROR!`. This will happen regardless of whether a code change was made.
See photo below:

[image]

NOTE: `Internal error executing the custom function.` is not one of our error strings.

This is very strange because the function does not seem to be executing. I say this because `#ERROR!` is returned immediately, with 0 processing time. See failures in photo below:

[image]

This issue resolves itself after some seemingly arbitrary amount of time. Meaning the custom function will run normally, after some seemingly arbitrary amount of time.

This has become a very large problem because we have uncontrollable downtime after each deployment, and it does not seem to be an issue with our code considering this happens every time we **deploy** the code, regardless of whether the code actually changed.

This Google [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) states `A custom function call must return within 30 seconds. If it does not, the cell will display an error: Internal error executing the custom function.`. Our custom function does not take 30s to run. We actually can't even find an instance where our function runs longer than 5s.

NOTE: the only thing that fails is our custom function, our task pane that interacts with the Google Sheet remains functional.

Comment: This looks to be something to be posted on the Google Apps Script issue tracker rather than here.

Comment: Please provide [mcve], without it we cannot confirm or troubleshoot the problem

Comment: Did you use the custom function on each cell?

Comment: @NikkoJ. yes we use the custom function on each cell. T

Comment: @Cooper there is no minimal reproducible example because the function never runs as you can see from the logs

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Optimization section of Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization):

> Each time a custom function is used in a spreadsheet, Google Sheets
> makes a separate call to the Apps Script server.

Having multiple custom functions means you are making multiple calls to the server simultaneously. This could lead to a slow process or sometimes **Error**.

**Solution:**

The workaround to this is to lessen the use of custom functions. Custom function can accept range as parameter and it will be translated as two-dimensional array in Apps Script. Use the array to calculate the values and return a two-dimensional array that can overflow into the appropriate cells in your spreadsheet.

**Example:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function multiplicationTable(row, col){
  var table = [];
  var rowArr = row.flat();
  var colArr = col.flat();
  for (var i = 0; i < rowArr.length ; i++) {
    table.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        table[i].push(rowArr[i] * colArr[j]);
    }
  } 
  return table;
}
```